# How to make offline payment type as prepaid in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, cash-on-delivery

I created a offline payment method for admin. If I use that payment method to create an order means it showing as **COD** as the payment method type. But I want to make as **Prepaid**.

Comment: You just need to change title from COD to Prepaid or anything else

Comment: I changed the title in config.xml but it didn't work. where do I need to change?

Comment: You can create a new order status: `Prepaid`. Assign this status to `pending` state. Go to `SALES > Payment Methods > Cash On Delivery Payment > New Order Status > change to Prepaid`.

Comment: is this will change the payment type COD to  Prepaid?

Comment: @Arul can you add screenshot where exactly you need to change title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the solution by I changed the following code

```
/**
 * @var string
protected $_code            = 'prepaid';
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $_gatewayCode      = 'prepaid';
```